# If I have a reference to a bound method in Python, will that alone keep the object alive?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote something like this today (not unlike the mpl_connect documentation:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self): print 'init Foo', self
    def __del__(self): print 'del Foo', self
    def callback(self, event=None): print 'Foo.callback', self, event


from pylab import *
fig = figure()
plot(randn(10))
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', Foo().callback)
show()
```

This looks reasonable, but it doesn't work -- it's as though matplotlib loses track of the function I've given it. If instead of passing it `Foo().callback` I pass it `lambda e: Foo().callback(e)`, it works. Similarly if I say `x = Foo()` and then pass it `x.callback`, it works.

My presumption is that the unnamed Foo instance created by `Foo()` is immediately destroyed after the `mpl_connect` line -- that matplotlib having the `Foo.callback` reference doesn't keep the `Foo` alive. Is that correct?

In the non-toy code I encountered this in, the solution of `x = Foo()` didn't work, presumably because in that case `show()` was elsewhere so `x` had gone out of scope.

More generally, `Foo().callback` is a `<bound method Foo.callback of <__main__.Foo object at 0x03B37890>>`. My primary surprise is that it seems like a bound method isn't actually keeping a reference to the object. Is that correct?

Comment: Does `'del Foo'` ever get printed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a bound method references the object - the object is the value of a bound method object's `.im_self` attribute.

So I'm wondering whether `matplotlib`'s `mpl_connect()` is remembering to increment the reference counts on the arguments passed to it.  If not (and this is a common error), then there's nothing to keep the anonymous `Foo().callback` alive when `mpl_connect()` returns.

If you have easy access to the source code, take a look at the `mpl_connect()` implementation?  You want to see C code doing `Py_INCREF()` ;-)

**EDIT** This looks relevant, [from docs here](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html):

> The canvas retains only weak references to the callbacks. Therefore
>   if a callback is a method of a class instance, you need to retain
>   a reference to that instance. Otherwise the instance will be garbage-
>   collected and the callback will vanish.

So it's **your** fault - LOL ;-)

Comment: `mpl_connect` of `FigureCanvasBase` use `weakref.WeakKeyDictionary` and `weakref.ref`. [Related source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/63f13c8d16c2b53ec2380b67f5b6ab45f6193bf9/lib/matplotlib/cbook.py#L474)

Comment: @falsetru, yup, just edited to show that the docs even say so.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I jumped to the examples they give, but when the call to `show` is out of scope, no dice.

Comment: I do wonder why they made that design decision. I can't think when that would be preferable behavior to holding a strong reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the justification from `matplotlib.cbook.CallbackRegistry.__doc__`:

> In practice, one should always disconnect all callbacks when they
>   are no longer needed to avoid dangling references (and thus memory
>   leaks).  However, real code in matplotlib rarely does so, and due
>   to its design, it is rather difficult to place this kind of code.
>   To get around this, and prevent this class of memory leaks, we
>   instead store weak references to bound methods only, so when the
>   destination object needs to die, the CallbackRegistry won't keep
>   it alive.  The Python stdlib weakref module can not create weak
>   references to bound methods directly, so we need to create a proxy
>   object to handle weak references to bound methods (or regular free
>   functions).  This technique was shared by Peter Parente on his
>   `"Mindtrove" blog
>   <http://mindtrove.info/articles/python-weak-references/>`_.

It's a shame there isn't an official way to bypass this behavior.

Here's a kludge to get around it, which is dirty but may be OK for non-production test/diagnostic code: attach the `Foo` the the figure:

```
fig._dont_forget_this = Foo()
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', fig._dont_forget_this.callback)
```

This still leaves the question of why `lambda e: Foo().callback(e)` works. It obviously makes a new `Foo` at every call, but why doesn't the lambda get garbage collected? Is the fact that it works just a case of undefined behavior?

Comment: You'd think at very least `mpl_connect` could have a `strongref` argument so you could say `fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', strongref=Foo().callback)`